# Terraform: use not-yet-existent service account credentials to configure Google provider

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We are using Terraform 1.6.3 with [`google v5.8.0`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/5.8.0/docs) provider. We would like to automate project creation, service account & key creation and compute engine deployment. We would like to authenticate against Google's APIs using a service account and its JSON key (which should be created by Terraform as well).

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "5.8.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "google" {
  project = google_project.test_hosting.name
  credentials = local_file.terraform_json_file.filename
}

resource "google_project" "test_hosting" {
  auto_create_network = true
  name                = "test-hosting"
  org_id              = "123456789"
  project_id          = "test-hosting"
}

resource "google_service_account" "terraform" {
  account_id   = "terraform"
  description  = "Service account for Terraform"
  display_name = "terraform"
  project      = google_project.test_hosting.name
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "terraform_json_key" {
  service_account_id = google_service_account.terraform.id
}

resource "local_file" "terraform_json_file" {
  content   = "${base64decode(google_service_account_key.terraform_json_key.private_key)}"
  filename  = "${path.root}/terraform_credentials.json"
}
```

When we run `terraform init` and then `terraform plan`, we get the following error:

```
Error: Cycle: google_service_account_key.terraform_json_key, local_file.terraform_json_file, google_project.test_hosting, provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google"], google_service_account.terraform
```

Obviously, the error is expected because Terraform requires `google` provider to be configured before it can even create a service account using its `google_service_account` resource.

However, is our requirement achievable? We would like to automate everything from the complete beginning - project creation, service account and key creation, network and firewall configuration, compute engine deployment etc. All of this should be done by the service account which is not-yet-existent and must be created with `google_service_account` resource. This seems like a common use-case for other companies which are using IaC approach. How is this use-case tackled in the industry?

Comment: It's not achievable in a single Terraform deployment. The values you configure inside the `provider` block can't be things you are expecting Terraform to create during the `apply` phase.

Comment: Hey Aleks, 
I'm using approach in which you'll have a separated `backend` terraform standalone application that will configure google service account altogether with preparing resources needed for store a backend configuration. This application can use local backend for storing state, since it will be a pretty small and almost immutable.

Once you setup your `backend` app, you will have all resources you need in order to setup other applications.

Let me know if you would like me to give you some examples.

Comment: @MarkB What would be the best approach then? To set up Application Default Credentials with `gcloud auth application-default login` on my local PC, omit `credentials` inside the `provider` block and create the project with Terraform (`terraform apply`)? When this is done, should I manually log into GCP Console, create a service account and generate its key, download the key and reference the JSON key in `credentials` section of `google` block? From then on, all Terraform commands will be executed in the name of service accoount. Is there any better/more automated way?

Comment: @IlyaKhrustalev Yes please, an example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Mind me asking why you want to use a JSON key to begin with? You should choose a more secure alternative to service account keys whenever possible: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#auth-decision-tree

Comment: @vpgcloud Based on the linked diagram, we decided to use service account impersonation. We found the [official tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/using-google-cloud-service-account-impersonation-your-terraform-code) which explains how to retrieve short-lived token using Terraform. However, the original issue still persists: service account has to exist first in order to impersonate it (`target_service_account` parameter in `data "google_service_account_access_token"` block).

Comment: Could you update your sample code to the latest version?

Comment: @vpgcloud I posted another question with the latest sample code repository: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77805557.