# Terraform: configure Google provider with not-yet-existent service account (impersonation)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

We are using Terraform 1.6.3 with [`google v5.11.0`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/5.11.0/docs) provider. We would like to automate everything right from the beginning - project creation, service account `serviceacc` creation and Google provider configuration with service account `serviceacc` impersonation without having to run `terraform apply` multiple times or having to change the code during the `terraform apply` commands.

We have the following folder structure. All of the code is also available in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/aleksvujic/TerraformServiceAccountImpersonation/tree/9c21d61ebdf1d7a2f0b89677753c69472ce63200).

```
|-- IAMServiceAccount
|   |-- _outputs.tf
|   |-- _required_providers.tf
|   |-- _variables.tf
|   `-- terraform.tf
|-- IAMServiceAccountBinding
|   |-- _required_providers.tf
|   |-- _variables.tf
|   `-- bindings.tf
|-- Project
|   |-- _outputs.tf
|   |-- _required_providers.tf
|   `-- demo.tf
|-- Service
|   |-- _required_providers.tf
|   |-- _variables.tf
|   `-- services.tf
`-- main.tf
```

### IAMServiceAccount folder

`IAMServiceAccount/_outputs.tf`:

```hcl
output "terraform_service_account" {
  value = {
    name  = google_service_account.terraform.name
    email = google_service_account.terraform.email
  }
}
```

`IAMServiceAccount/_variables.tf`:

```hcl
variable "demo_project_id" {
  type = string
}
```

`IAMServiceAccount/terraform.tf`:

```hcl
resource "google_service_account" "terraform" {
  account_id   = "terraform"
  description  = "Service account for Terraform"
  display_name = "terraform"
  project      = var.demo_project_id
}
```

### IAMServiceAccountBinding folder

`IAMServiceAccountBinding/_variables.tf`:

```hcl
variable "terraform_service_account" {
  type = object({
    name  = string
    email = string
  })
}
```

`IAMServiceAccountBinding/bindings.tf`:

```hcl
resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "iam_serviceAccountTokenCreator" {
  service_account_id = var.terraform_service_account.name
  role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"

  members = [
    "user: name.surname@company.com"
  ]
}
```

### Project folder

`Project/_outputs.tf`:

```hcl
output "demo_project_id" {
  value = google_project.demo.project_id
}
```

`Project/demo.tf`:

```hcl
resource "google_project" "demo" {
  auto_create_network = true
  name                = "optimistic-darwin-fervent"
  org_id              = "ORG_ID"
  project_id          = "optimistic-darwin-fervent"
}
```

### Service folder

`Service/_variables.tf`:

```hcl
variable "demo_project_id" {
  type = string
}
```

`Service/services.tf`:

```hcl
resource "google_project_service" "gcp_services" {
  for_each = toset([
    "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com",
    "iam.googleapis.com",
    "serviceusage.googleapis.com",
  ])
  project = var.demo_project_id
  service = each.key
  disable_on_destroy = false
  timeouts {

  }
}
```

### Root folder

`main.tf`

```hcl
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "5.11.0"
    }
  }
}

##########################
# provider configuration #
##########################
provider "google" {
  alias = "demo"
  project = module.demo-Project.demo_project_id
  access_token = data.google_service_account_access_token.default.access_token
}


provider "google" {
 alias = "impersonation"
 scopes = [
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 ]
}


data "google_service_account_access_token" "default" {
 provider                   = google.impersonation
 target_service_account     = module.demo-IAMServiceAccount.terraform_service_account.email
 scopes                     = ["userinfo-email", "cloud-platform"]
 lifetime                   = "1200s"
}


##########################
######### modules ########
##########################
module "demo-IAMServiceAccount" {
  source = "./IAMServiceAccount"
  providers = {
    google = google.demo
  }

  demo_project_id = module.demo-Project.demo_project_id
}


module "demo-IAMServiceAccountBinding" {
  source = "./IAMServiceAccountBinding"
  providers = {
    google = google.demo
  }

  terraform_service_account = module.demo-IAMServiceAccount.terraform_service_account
}


module "demo-Project" {
  source = "./Project"
  providers = {
    google = google.demo
  }
}


module "demo-Service" {
  source = "./Service"
  providers = {
    google = google.demo
  }

  demo_project_id = module.demo-Project.demo_project_id
}
```

File `_required_providers.tf` has the same content in all folders:

```hcl
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
    }
  }
}
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. `gcloud auth application-default login` and login with `name.surname@company.com` (same account as in `IAMServiceAccountBinding/bindings.tf`).
2. `terraform init`
3. `terraform apply`

After running 3rd step, the following error is thrown:

```
Error: Cycle: module.demo-IAMServiceAccount.output.terraform_service_account (expand), data.google_service_account_access_token.default, provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google"].demo, module.demo-Project.google_project.demo, module.demo-Project.output.demo_project_id (expand), module.demo-IAMServiceAccount.var.demo_project_id (expand), module.demo-IAMServiceAccount.google_service_account.terraform
```

We would like to provision everything from the very beggining with Terraform (starting with project and service account creation). We would also like to use service account impersonation (hence the `google_service_account_iam_binding.iam_serviceAccountTokenCreator` resource). Is this achievable in the single `terraform apply` run? How is this use-case handled in the industry?

Comment: You can't! Terraform compile files, check dependencies, generate token and run the jobs. In your case, the dependencies and the generate token can't be achieved, so no job is ran. You must have, at least 2 run: 1 to create the correct project landscape (the minimal to run a terraform in a project) -> The project factory. Then a 2nd run to deploy the resource inside the project, with the correct service account impersonation, (...). You must set this order yourselves, else you create a loop (a cycle) and terraform can't solved it without opinionated choice.

Comment: it is like a chicken egg problem which you're trying to solve :)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Must such use-cases be developed iteratively? First, `google_project`, `google_service_account` and `google_service_account_iam_binding` should be created with ADC. Then, we can add `data "google_service_account_access_token"` which retrieves access token for before-generated service account and pass it to `provider "google"`. All modules except `demo-Project` can then use `google.demo` provider from then on. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Prany Exactly. I was interested in how to deal with such cases. Apparently, developers are forced to develop resources iteratively and change module's `providers` section accordingly (based on the fact if service account exists and has token creator role enabled for the currently logged in user).

Comment: Yes, it's correct!